# Lagrange Method for Linear PDE with 3 independent variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I have 2 questions

1. Suppose i have this pde

$x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}+t\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}=xyt$

And the auxiliary equation is

$\dfrac{\partial x}{x}=\dfrac{\partial y}{y}=\dfrac{\partial t}{t}=\dfrac{\partial z}{xyt}$

I know that the last solution will be has this form :

$\Phi(a,b,c)=0$

So, i have to find out what $a$, $b$, and $c$ are.

From  $\dfrac{\partial x}{x}=\dfrac{\partial y}{y}$,  i got  $a=\dfrac{x}{y}$

From $\dfrac{\partial y}{y}=\dfrac{\partial t}{t}$,  i got $b=\dfrac{y}{t}$

2. And i want to write $\Phi(a,b,c)=0$ as explicit in $z$ so, i have to solve for $dz$

Suppose i want to solve for

$\dfrac{\partial t}{t}=\dfrac{\partial z}{xyt}$

And i'm stuck here. I was confused with the denominator $xyt$ that is not has $z$ term. How do i solve this? 
And we know, if i have a solution $F(a,b)=0$, it can be written in explicit term as $F(a)=b$.

But how about 3 variables that is in my case i have a solution $\Phi(a,b,c)=0$?

Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: 1. What does it matter if the denominator of the fraction containing $dz$ has no $z$ term? If you want to solve $$\frac{dz}{xyt} = \frac{dt}{t}$$ then **if you know what $x, y$ are as functions of $t$**, then you can just integrate straight away. 2. \begin{align} \Phi(a,b,c) &= 0 \\ \implies a &= \phi(b,c) \end{align} Just so you know, the solution is given by $$z(x,y,t) = \frac{xyt}{3} + f \left(\frac{x}{t}, \frac{y}{t} \right)$$

Comment: Actually i can't explain correctly. Besides maybe i don't understand with this concept. Ok, and i know that $z$ isn't has effect on $dz$, and consider from $\frac{\partial t}{t}=\frac{\partial z}{xyt}$ i got $c=\frac{z}{xy}-t$. Then the complete solution is $\Phi(x/y, y/t, z/xy - t)$ but when i rewrite this as $z=xyt- \frac{xy^2}{t}+xyf\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\,$.it doesn't satisfied the equation.

Comment: It is wrong because, as I wrote in my previous comment, when you integrate $$\frac{dz}{xyt} = \frac{dt}{t}$$ **you need to know what $x, y$ are in terms of $t$** i.e $x = x(t), y = y(t)$. You can find both of these by integrating $$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dt}{t}$$ and $$\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dt}{t}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}+t\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}=xyt$$

$$\dfrac{d x}{x}=\dfrac{d y}{y}=\dfrac{d t}{t}=\dfrac{d z}{xyt}$$

A first characteristic equation comes from $\dfrac{d x}{x}=\dfrac{d y}{y}$
$$\frac{x}{y}=c_1 \tag 1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\dfrac{d y}{y}=\dfrac{d t}{t}$
$$\frac{y}{t}=c_2 \tag 2$$

A third characteristic equation comes from

$$\dfrac{d x}{x}=\dfrac{d y}{y}=\dfrac{d t}{t}= \frac{(yt)dx+(xt)dy+(xy)dt}{(yt)x+(xt)y+(xy)t}=\dfrac{d (xyt)}{3(xyt)}=\dfrac{d z}{xyt}\qquad\text{See note below.}$$
$$z-\frac13 xyt=c_3 \tag 3$$

General solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $\Phi(c_1, c_2,c_3)=0$

Or equivalently on the form : $c_3=F(c_1, c_2)=z-\frac13 xyt=F\left(\frac{x}{y}\:,\:\frac{y}{t} \right)$

$$\boxed{z(x,y,t)=\frac13 xyt+F\left(\frac{x}{y}\:,\:\frac{y}{t} \right)}$$
This consistent with the result from Mathos $z(x,y,t)=\frac13 xyt+f\left(\frac{x}{t}\:,\:\frac{y}{t} \right)$ since $F$ and $f$ are both arbitrary functions : $F(X,Y)=f(XY,Y)$.

NOTE : The relationship between equal fractions is a well known property in elementary fraction calculus. If $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}$ then  $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{k_1A+k_2C}{k_1B+k_2D}$ with any $k_1, k_2$ not both nul.